# How can I refactor in Helios with Subclipse without problems committing changes?

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I am running Eclipse Helio with Subclipse on Windows XP.

When I do simple refactoring in Java that results in folders being deleted, commit fails. I can get around this one folder at a time by "update to head" and then "Mark Resolved" but this is very tedious.

In more complex refactors, things seem to get tangled where even that doesn't work.

I am not doing anything weird like going outside of eclipse to move files around, etc.

Help! This makes SVN almost unusable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is exactly the use case, but I haven't seen such behavior. try to ***synchronize*** before you do the actual commit.
Team -> synchronize...

Comment: Oops... hit enter too soon. Here is the use case: Java package a.b.c refactored to a.b.d - the result is a/b/c directory is deleted. Subclipse marks it with a red X. When I go to commit the project, it always claims tree conflict. Why can't it just understand that I deleted the directory and want it deleted? After all, if I create a directory or modify a file, it doesn't require me to sync before committing.

Comment: More info... note that in my use case, I am the only user of the SVN repository. In fact, it is on my laptop. So there isn't a version conflict with anyone else checking stuff in before my commit.